# Does JVM @PactUrl provide basic auth options?

Tags: java, pact

I want to consumer a pact contract file from a url with basic auth. Does JVM @PactUrl provide basic auth options? If not, is there a way to provide it somewhere else when using "@pacturl"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only using basic auth, couldn't you use the URL in @PactUrl to have the username/password?

Like this `https://foo:password@example.com`?

That being said, I think it would be good to have a way to authenticate for all pacts so that the username/password doesn't have to be repeated over and over throughout the codebase.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case, there is no way to include the username and password in the URL. Can I write my own annotation interface with basic auth options and make it happen? Something like `@MyUrl(urls = , username = , password = )`

Comment: One way to fix it would be to make it go through a local proxy/http intercepter and add the username/password to the URL.  I don't think that the annotation does authentication currently. I see that you had already created an issue with [pact-jvm](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/issues/430) which is great.  If you did extend it, maybe it might be a good idea to also create a pull request for your change so that others can benefit from the work.  Thanks :)